# how to print dataset without formats in SAS

Tags: sas, format

I ´have a dataset with formats attached to it and I dont want to remove the formats from the dataset and when I use proc freq or proc print, I want the original values and not the formats attached.

```
Proc print data=mylib.data; 
run;
```

is there any format=no option?

```
proc freq data=mylib.data; 
tables gender; 
format?????
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove a format by specifying a null format on the PROC strep:

```
proc freq data=mylib.data ; 
tables gender ; 
format _ALL_ ;
run ;
```

`_ALL_` is a list of all variables in the dataset.